# Why is my Alamofire router not giving me the right URL request?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have constructed an Alamofire router and for some reason, when I make a request call (using my router, I get a build error, as can be seen below. [image]

I don't really get why my router isn't doing its job since this is how I constructed my router for my last project and it worked fine...

Here is the code for my router:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
        static var baseRequestURL = ""

        case GetAnAccessToken
        case ListAllVehicles
        case MobileAccess

        var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
            var result: String = {
                switch self {
                case .GetAnAccessToken:
                    Router.baseRequestURL = NetworkingVariables.loginURL
                    return ("")
                case .ListAllVehicles:
                    Router.baseRequestURL = NetworkingVariables.baseURL
                    return ("")
                case .MobileAccess:
                    Router.baseRequestURL = NetworkingVariables.baseURL
                    return ("/vehicle_id/mobile_enabled")
                }
            }()

            let baseEndpointURL = NSURL(string: Router.baseRequestURL)
            let endpointRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: baseEndpointURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(result))
            return endpointRequest
        }
    }
```

And here is my Alamofire call:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Networking.Router.GetAnAccessToken , parameters: parameters)
                .responseJSON() { response in
```

What do I need to modify in my router for it to properly hand me the URLRequest, so that I can successfully complete my HTTP Request ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two `Alamofire.request` signatures, one takes a URLRequestConvertible whereas the other takes a URLStringConvertible, and you have mixed the two.

I haven't tested it, but I think the following will work:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Networking.Router.GetAnAccessToken.URLRequest , parameters: parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your router is creating a URL request. But it should also be setting the HTTP method (.POST) and parameters on the URL request. So then you won't pass those separately when calling Alamofire.request(), since they're part of the URL request. So your `.request` call should look like this:

```
Alamofire.request(Networking.Router.GetAnAccessToken.URLRequest)
```

Here's an example of a router setting the HTTP method and params:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum PostRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
  static let baseURLString = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"

  case Get(Int)
  case Create([String: AnyObject])
  case Delete(Int)

  var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
    var method: Alamofire.Method {
      switch self {
      case .Get:
        return .GET
      case .Create:
        return .POST
      case .Delete:
        return .DELETE
      }
    }

    let params: ([String: AnyObject]?) = {
      switch self {
      case .Get, .Delete:
        return (nil)
      case .Create(let newPost):
        return (newPost)
      }
    }()

    let url:NSURL = {
      // build up and return the URL for each endpoint
      let relativePath:String?
      switch self {
      case .Get(let postNumber):
        relativePath = "posts/\(postNumber)"
      case .Create:
        relativePath = "posts"
      case .Delete(let postNumber):
        relativePath = "posts/\(postNumber)"
      }

      var URL = NSURL(string: PostRouter.baseURLString)!
      if let relativePath = relativePath {
        URL = URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(relativePath)
      }
      return URL
    }()

    let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
    let (encodedRequest, _) = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: params)

    encodedRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

    return encodedRequest
  }
}
```

*Code taken from my blog post at https://grokswift.com/router/*